# How to run Scheduled Jobs/Scripts on Parse Server Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, scheduled-tasks, parse-server

I have an application that would record user's days since last logged-in so active users will be prioritized. I would jsut need to update a column everyday and increment one to it. Does anyone know how to do this? I have seen some threads regarding Parse scheduled jobs for Javascript but not Android.

Would I be able to deploy my own scheduled job on Parse Server? What language would this script be in and how? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752809/parse-server-how-to-use-a-scheduler-to-run-jobs-over-and-over  similar faq

Comment: Can you not just set Date field on the user called `lastActive`, and just sort by descending? If that approach doesn't work, I use forever.js and pm2 to do scheduled tasks. I don't think that Parse Server supports scheduled jobs at the moment

Comment: @LulzCow Oh, I haven't thought of that. That should actually suit my needs. Thanks!